# Fix TypeScript error in a function that groups an array of objects by multiple keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a function that groups an array of objects by multiple keys:

```js
export function groupByMulti<T>(dataset: T[], keys: Array<keyof T>) {
  if (keys.length === 0) {
    return dataset
  }
  const byFirst = groupBy(dataset, keys[0])
  const rest = keys.slice(1)
  for (const prop in byFirst) {
    // HERE there is a TypeScript error
    // Type 'T[] | Dictionary<T[]>' is not assignable to type 'T[]'
    byFirst[prop] = groupByMulti(byFirst[prop], rest)
  }
  return byFirst
}
```

How can I solve this error? I absolutely don't want to use a `ts-ignore`

Comment: What is the return type of `groupBy` function?

Comment: @Ardalan `Dictionary<T>`

Comment: Can you send the `Dictionary` type too? I want to reproduce